# How do you iterate one level at a time?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, iteration, domdocument

Let's say I have something like this and it can't be changed:

```
<xml>
<element name="breakfast" type="sandwich" />
<element name="lunch">
  <complexType>
    <element name="meat" type="string" />
    <element name="vegetables" type="vegetable" />
    <element name="chips" type="boolean" />
  </complexType>
</element>
<complexType name="sandwich">
  <element name="bread" type="string" />
  <element name="cheese" type="int" />
  <element name="butter" type="boolean" />
</complexType>
<complexType name="vegetable">
  <element name="tomato" type="int" />
  <element name="lettuce" type="boolean" />
  <element name="carrot" type="boolean" />
</complexType>
<element name="dinner" type="sandwich" />
</xml>
```

I want some sort of array / object like:

```
var day = {
  time: {
    breakfast: {
      bread: "string",
      cheese: "int",
      butter: "boolean"
    },
    lunch: {
      meat: "string",
      vegetables: {
        tomato: "int",
        lettuce: "boolean",
        carrot: "boolean"
      },
      chips: "boolean"
    },
    dinner: {
      bread: "string",
      cheese: "int",
      butter: "boolean"
    },
  },
  food: {
    sandwich: {
      bread: "string",
      cheese: "int",
      butter: "boolean"
    },
    vegetable: {
      tomato: "int",
      lettuce: "boolean",
      carrot: "boolean"
    },
  }
}
```

I don't mind what language, PHP or JavaScript would be great but I really just want to see the logic. I am sure there is a standard pattern for this.

At the moment I have something along the lines of:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($data);

$day = array(
  "time" => array(),
  "food" => array()
);
getLevel1($xml->childNodes[0]);

function getLevel1(DOMNode $domNode) {
  global $day;
  foreach ($domNode->childNodes as $node) {
    if ($node->nodeName == "element") {
      if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
        $day["time"][$node->getAttribute('name')] = getLevel2($node);
      } else {
        if (isset($day["food"][$node->getAttribute('type')])) {
          $day["time"][$node->getAttribute('name')] = $day["food"][$node->getAttribute('type')];
        } else {
          $day["time"][$node->getAttribute('name')] = $node->getAttribute('type');  
        }
      }
    };
    if ($node->nodeName == "complexType") {
      if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
        $day["food"][$node->getAttribute('name')] = getLevel2($node);
      } else {
        $day["food"][$node->getAttribute('name')] = $node->getAttribute('type');
      }
    };
  }
};

function getLevel2(DOMNode $domNode) {
  $object = array();
  foreach ($domNode->childNodes as $node) {
    if ($node->nodeName == "element") {
      $object[$node->getAttribute('name')] = $node->getAttribute('type');
    };
    if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
      if ($node->hasAttribute('name')) {
        $object[$node->getAttribute('name')] = getLevel2($node);
      } else {
        return getLevel2($node);
      }
    }
  }
  return $object;
}

print_r($day);
```

Output: [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1dd4f60b3e18899000eef3ab1caca0b57c28c064)

I can see why breakfast does not show because it does not exist at the time so I need a better way to iterate.

Comment: Use `simpleXML`!

Comment: Also there is no `food` or `day` or `time` in your original xml-data. The only thing i can see is that your use complexType with names `<complexType name="vegetable">` as sub object/array in the result json when the element type matches. Seems that is an XSD not an XML file. The rest is very unclear.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Yes I define food, day and time in the PHP. Yes it is an XSD but really just want the logic behind looping over the first level of an array before going through the children.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more function that replaces all known types (I called it `replaceComplexTypes`):

```
<?php

$data = '<xml>
<element name="breakfast" type="sandwich" />
<element name="lunch">
  <complexType>
    <element name="meat" type="string" />
    <element name="vegetables" type="vegetable" />
    <element name="chips" type="boolean" />
  </complexType>
</element>
<complexType name="sandwich">
  <element name="bread" type="string" />
  <element name="cheese" type="int" />
  <element name="butter" type="boolean" />
</complexType>
<complexType name="vegetable">
  <element name="tomato" type="int" />
  <element name="lettuce" type="boolean" />
  <element name="carrot" type="boolean" />
</complexType>
<element name="dinner" type="sandwich" />
</xml>';
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($data);

$day = getLevel1($xml->childNodes[0]);
$day2 = replaceComplexTypes($day['time'], $day['food']);
$day = array('time' => $day2, 'food' => $day['food']);

function getLevel1(DOMNode $domNode) {
  $day = array(
    "time" => array(),
    "food" => array()
  );
  foreach ($domNode->childNodes as $node) {
    if ($node->nodeName == "element") {
      if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
        $day["time"][$node->getAttribute('name')] = getLevel2($node);
      } else {
          if (isset($day["food"][$node->getAttribute('type')])) {
            $day["time"][$node->getAttribute('name')] = $day["food"][$node->getAttribute('type')];
          } else {
            $day["time"][$node->getAttribute('name')] = $node->getAttribute('type');  
          }
      }
    };
    if ($node->nodeName == "complexType") {
      if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
        $day["food"][$node->getAttribute('name')] = getLevel2($node);
      } else {
        $day["food"][$node->getAttribute('name')] = $node->getAttribute('type');
      }
    };
  }
  return $day;
}

function getLevel2(DOMNode $domNode) {
  $object = array();
  foreach ($domNode->childNodes as $node) {
    if ($node->nodeName == "element") {
      $object[$node->getAttribute('name')] = $node->getAttribute('type');
    };
    if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
      if ($node->hasAttribute('name')) {
        $object[$node->getAttribute('name')] = getLevel2($node);
      } else {
        return getLevel2($node);
      }
    }
  }
  return $object;
}

function replaceComplexTypes(array $replaceIn, array $replaceWith) {
  $output = array();
  foreach ($replaceIn as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
      $output[$key] = replaceComplexTypes($value, $replaceWith);
    }
    else {
      if (array_key_exists($value, $replaceWith)) {
        $output[$key] = $replaceWith[$value];
      }
      else {
        $output[$key] = $value;
      }
    }
  }
  return $output;
}

print_r($day);
```